# Is there any browser which supports regular expression?

Tags: regex, browser

I'm looking for a browser which its find-system *(Ctrl + F)* supports regex. I've searched about that, but I didn't find any browser.

Is there any recommendation? Or is there any extension to add that regex-property to the browser?

Comment: Use google, there are plenty of results. This is no programming specific question and in addition, an opinion based question which does not belong here. Search for 'Chrome Regex Search' will probably be what you are looking for....

Comment: @Xavjer I've searched before asking but unfortunately no result. Thx anyway, I'll keep searching ..!

Comment: This _might_ be on-topic on [SoftwareRecs.SE]. As always, see if it hasn't been answered there already. If it hasn't, be sure to read their Help Center before posting; they are very strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has a extension that does it:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-search/bcdabfmndggphffkchfdcekcokmbnkjl

Firefox has one too.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regex-find/

Comment: Seems useful .. thx. +1

Comment: I will not even try to find one for IE ;-)

Comment: Hah ... agreed ;-)